# Single quotation marks in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to get rid of the quotation marks from a list that I have.
I have this:

```
Letcodea =
     ['F',
     'G',
     'L',
     'Q',
     'P',
     'F',
     'G',
     'L',
     'Q',
     'P',
     'F',
     'G',
     'L',
     'Q',
     'P',
     'F',
     'G',
     'L',
     'Q',
     'P']
```

And them using a simple code I have this:

```
gamma = []
    omega = [','.join(map(repr, letcodea))]
    for oem in omega:
        oem = oem.replace("'", "")
        gamma.append(oem)
    gamma

    ['F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P']
```

Does anyone knows hoy can I eliminate those quotations marks at the beginning and end of a list? Thank you in advance

Comment: You seem to be confused. You cannot "get rid of the quotation marks" because they are *not a part of the data*, in the same way that the square brackets are not a part of the data. They are part of *how Python tells you* what *type of thing* you have.

Comment: you realize that `'F'` is a string containing the letter F, whereas `F` is the variable named F, right?

Comment: If I write it with print() I will get it without those ' ' but I need that omega just with brackets because I will each element as an input for other script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
print('[' + ','.join(Letcodea) + ']')
```

or if you really want to use all that extra code:

```
gamma = []
omega = [','.join(map(repr, Letcodea))]
for oem in omega:
    oem = oem.replace("'", "")
    gamma.append(oem)
print('[' + gamma[0] + ']')
```

Either way, you get:

```
[F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P,F,G,L,Q,P]
```